# Increase iframe height dynamically

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to integrate games into my phpfox social network. The code that comes for it is by a 3rd party and is something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                $('body').append('<iframe id="crossdomain_frame" src="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>static/crossdomain.php?height=' + document.body.scrollHeight + '&nocache=' + Math.random() + '" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
            });     
        </script>
```

On setting things up  the height of the frame is messed up. I can't understand how to increase the height. On viewing the page source code when it loads I find that the `<iframe>` doesn't even have the `height` and `width` attributes in the page. Could any one please help?

P.S you can check out for yourself what the page looks like by opening http://social.techbreeze.in/index.php?do=/apps/4/candy-rush/  and logging in using your facebook account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height of iframe using jquery after you append iframe to body.,

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
       $('body').append('<iframe id="crossdomain_frame" src="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>static/crossdomain.php?height=' + document.body.scrollHeight + '&nocache=' + Math.random() + '" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
       $('#crossdomain_frame').css('height', $(window).height()+'px');
});
```